# How can i change volume without manipulating overall phone's sounds volume

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in java:

```
volume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
audiomanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVol = audiomanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int currentVol = audiomanager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
volume.setMax(maxVol);
volume.setProgress(currentVol);
volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                    audiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

everything works fine, the only problem I have is I would like it not to manipulate overall phone's sounds volume. When i move the seekbar, sounds volume on the phone is changing also. Is there a way i can change volume of music playing in app, no matter what's the overall sounds volume?
For example:
User has seekbar set on maximum value but since they have muted overall phone's sounds the music will not be audible

```
                                                                      .
```